# Skipping Java compilation errors

Tags: java

Is it possible to Skip Java compilation errors?

So the program may continue even if it encountered errors.

So it kinda does the max effort to continue working (until everything explodes)

Comment: do you mean runtime errors?

Comment: do you mean, a single file or whole project?

Comment: what's a use of a program that can't even run. (you can always comment stuffs).

Comment: @domfarr that doesn't have accepted answers

Comment: "so the program may continue" <-- a program which does not compile will not run anyway, since there will be no program

Comment: No.What is the use of that???

Answer (score 4):

No. If you get compilation errors, it means your program is not valid Java. What would it even mean for it to continue? It's not running yet.

Answer (score 2):

If you have **compilation** errors, the program cannot be compiled to **runtime** code. That means practically that the program cannot be run.

So, the answer is **NO**, it cannot.

There is another type of errors - **runtime** errors. Those happens as a result of bad logic in the code (i.e. trying to modify a null object). Compiler cannot discover those as those are very subtle, depending-on-data (and most of the time depending on user input) errors. You can skip over those with the usage of a **try-catch** block. If you want to read more, please refer to this article:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that using the eclipse compiler. It will replace the method which contains the error with a method that will directly throw an Exception when it is invoked.

This will allow you to run the rest of the program. I would not recommend it though, as you'll get an inconsistent program. So use at your own risk.

Still it might come in handy, for example if you run unittests. This allows you to run tests, even if parts of your program are definitely not working.

Answer (score 1):

**No** its **just not possible**. Compilation of java code gives you the byte code which is then run on JVM. If the compilation will fail then Java compiler will not be able to generate valid byte code. Thats the reason that  there is no point in generating the incorrect byte code which can't be run by JVM as such.

Answer (score 1):

if we break that thing then sooner or later no one will be develop the code. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well ... kind of.

Some IDEs allow you to run code that has compilation errors in it.  For example, Eclipse.

When you then try to execute (say) a method with a compilation error it, you get an exception whose message says something to the effect that there is a compilation error in this code.  In fact, the Eclipse compiler has compiled the method to a stub method that will just throw an exception.

Note that this behaviour is NOT endorsed by the JLS.  And personally, I think it is a bad idea to use this IDE feature.

---

IMO, a better approach is to comment out the parts of the code that are giving the compilation errors ... or just fix them.

Answer (score 0):

Your expecting to avoid `compilation errors`,  what do you thing ?if you avoid compilation errors will you get `.class` file? without `.class` file you cant imagine to run you code.
compilation errors arise when your code contain syntactical eroor. without proper syntax you cant do anything.
For more about compilation error see [THIS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/problems/)